# JZOS Batch Launcher sending -Xtrace stderr to a pipe

Tags: pipe, stderr, mainframe, zos, jzos

I have a requirement to exec JZOS with -Xtrace and capture the output into a pipe.  -Xtrace print=mt.... writes its output to "stderr" which is well-known file descriptor 2. I coded a tiny HelloWorld application that also writes to stdout and stderr and that works fine, going to //STDOUT and //STDERR as we would expect.

The Xtrace info is being written to //SYSOUT and I have been able to code //SYSOUT DD PATH='myfifo_pipe' and that works too.  The problem is that I an getting everything from JZOS in there too. I could write a program to filter //SYSOUT and pick off the Xtrace records, but it would be cleaner to get Xtrace to write out somewhere else.  It seems that JZOS is sending IT's stdout and stderr to //SYSOUT.  How can I get JZOS to split those?  Basically to implement something like //SYSERR?

Any clever ideas on how to do this?

Comment: The JZOS batch launcher is for launching batch jobs, not batch files. I have therefore removed your invalid [[tag:batch-file]] tag.

Comment: Thank you -- I am an infrequent user here.

Comment: A tag for JZOS would be good but it would not me me do that.

Comment: Almost every tag on StackOverflow has a clear description. The batch file tag, is for Windows, DOS, or OS/2 executable scripts which will invariably have a `.bat` or `.cmd` extension. Please try ro read the tag descriptions, it helps to prevent negativity/downvotes, and targets only appropriate helpers.

Comment: I have added tag `jzos`, but had to remove one for that. I removed the `java` tag, since this is not really a Java question.

Answer (score 0):

In the JZOS Toolkit reference [1], topic *Java SDK Options and System Properties*, I read:

> Java options and system properties are configured in the batch launcher via the
> IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable. These options may includes most
> options found on the standard ’java’ command line launcher, including -X and -D
> options. The table below includes options commonly used with the batch launcher;

In the table mentioned, there is a JZOS batch launcher option `jzos.merge.sysout={true|false}`, which is described as:

> If set to true when running under the batch launcher,
> Java’s System.out and System.err are redirected to
> DD:SYSOUT and DD:STDOUT/DD:STDERR are ignored.
> Default: false

Maybe the option is set to `true` in your envcironment. Try setting it to `false`.

[1] I could not find a workable link to the documentation, therefore I'm posting quotes from my local PDF copy.

Comment: I did not know about this, and its interesting, but my problem is the JVM itself, not the application.  The JVM is sending its (not the applications) stdout and stderr to //SYSOUT. -Xtrace send its output to stderr and because of this merging its showing up with all the other JVM's stdout.  What -Xtrace needs is for those not to be merged together. 

The application's stdout is correctly going to //STDOUT and its stderr is correctly going to //STDERR.

Comment: Ok, but then, this is a problem of the JVM, and not related to JZOS in any way, is it?

Comment: I understand you want to separate Xtrace output form any other output. IBM documents *-Xtrace:output=<filename>[,<size>[,<generations>]]* in [IBM SDK, Java Technology Edition / -Xtrace](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdk-java-technology/8?topic=options-xtrace) as: "Sends trace data to a file, optionally of a specific size and number of generations.*. Maybe that helps? Tell me if so, and I will ammend my answer.

Comment: Yes and no.  We originally did that at first but its output is limited to 36x2GB files.  I am expecting 850 to 12000 million records and that wont hold them all.  Also the time it took to process that was in hours.  What I am doing here is trying to grab the stderr and pump that (850M) into a program to ananlyze the records wofr what we seek. I also do not have access to the source code.  using print= seems the only option.  That's working, but its being mushed into STDOUT instead of "STDERR" (which does not exit (I think) ).

Comment: My current approach is to send STDOUT to a pipe (mkfifo) and then read that with a program to split out the data into an "STDOUT" file and send the Xtrace data onto my digester via a second pipe.  I have that working, but not under the JVM.

Comment: I think this is a JZOS issue. I believe is should support sending its stderr to //STDERR just like is does stdout to //STDOUT.  As I understand it JZOS sets up the JVM and gets it started.